# What would be the efficient way to resolve critical spring-web-5.3.28.jar vulnerability?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm running a vulnerability check on my project and it seems that Spring has a vulnerability on the spring-web-5.3.28.jar package:

[image: spring-web-vulnerability]

One solution I found is to update the spring boot version to 3 and spring framework to 6 and Java to 17. Currently, my project is running on spring boot version 2.7.13 and java version 11.

Can someone help me with what would be an efficient way to fix it?

Comment: Hi, can you please stop undoing my edits? Or at the very least please stop putting extra spaces before the picture and extra `[` and `]` around the link.

Comment: Instead of panicking because there is an alert have you actually **read** the alert and determined if you are affected. Feels like you are just checking boxes instead of doing some investigation.